# Is there a concrete implementation of OCRProcessor in openimaj

Tags: java, openimaj

I am trying to do text extraction using openimaj and I am using LiuSamarabanduTextExtractorBasic text extractor subclass. But this class needs an OCRProcessor implementation to do that actual OCR.
Following is the javadoc

```
public void setOCRProcessor(OCRProcessor<T> ocr)
```

*For the text regions that are extracted to be associated with textual representations of the text regions, an OCR processor must be used. Use this function to choose which OCR processor is used to extract read text regions.*

I did not find a implementation in openimaj library (which is strange if you ask me).

Is there an OCRProcessor implementaion that i can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there seems to be no implementation. I wrote a java wrapper around [tesseract-ocr](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) (platform dependent) for OCR.